# Why is SBT throwing error when running external process

Tags: sbt

I'm creating a task in SBT that will upload some scripts to S3. I'm uploading to S3 using *SBT external process* with aws cli `s"aws s3 cp ./someDir $uploadPath --recursive" ! log`.
It throws error

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "aws": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

This happens only on Windows. It works fine when I run the same project/task in Ubuntu build system. AWS cli is installed on Windows machine and PATH is set correctly.

Its not clear to me what is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the sbt internal process library does not include the PATH variables in windows.

A suitable workaround would be to extract your aws command in a separate file and trigger the execution of this file:

your doSomeStuff.bat would be:

```
aws s3 cp ./someDir $uploadPath --recursive
```

and in the build.sbt add

```
lazy val someStuff = taksKey[Unit]("Execute a aws command")
yarnBuild := {
    "./doSomeStuff.bat" !
}
```

Comment: I didn't go down this path as our team has a mix of Windows, Mac and Ubuntu users. Decided to write a plugin that uses API instead of CLI

Answer (score 0):

Another possible workaround is to run the command inside a shell (and you must know your shells for all "problematic" environments)

```
  val shell: Seq[String] = if (sys.props("os.name").contains("Windows")) Seq("cmd", "/c") else Seq("bash", "-c")
  val command: Seq[String] = shell :+ "<your command here>"
  command .!
```